# Mathematica antialiasing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graphics, wolfram-mathematica, antialiasing

I am interested in finding an [antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing) algorithm which can be used on a line of any shape (not just straight lines).

I notice that Mathematica seems to have a very good algorithm and can draw fine lines 1 or 2 pixels wide. My current best effort algorithm generally requires more like 3 pixels so my lines are somewhat thicker than Mathematica's.

Does anybody know what algorithm Mathematica uses for antialiasing, or can recommend a high-quality algorithm that can be used to generate sub-2-pixel antialiased lines and curves?

Comment: Can't you draw 3 separate lines three times?

Comment: The cleanest and simplest, but somewhat slow, antialiasing method is just oversampling. That is, draw the line at higher resolution than your actual display, and scale it down.

Comment: I am familiar with this method, and it is possible that Mathematica uses it, however examples I have seen don't seem to have very good quality all the time compared to Mathematica. Maybe I am just seeing things, but my suspicion is that they are using a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: I don't have much experience with manual oversampling but be aware that there are [**many**](http://www.general-cathexis.com/interpolation/index.html) different ways to rescale images; quite possibly the quality you seek can be had with a different resampling algorithm or [**filter**](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/).

Answer (score 3):

One of the most used algorithm for drawing unaliased lines is [Wu's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm).

On this basis, you can draw polygons easily; this [site](http://yellowsplash.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/fast-antialiased-circles-and-ellipses-from-xiaolin-wus-concepts/) explains how to derive this algorithm to draw ellipses.

Comment: I want to be able to draw arbitrary shapes, including for example, sin and cos (trigonometric functions), as well as higher order polynomials. Wu's algorithm is primarily for straight lines.

Comment: I think that the same approach can be applied for everything. See this post which mentions how to draw antialiased splines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541442/drawing-aliased-pixel-perfect-1px-splines-catmull-rom-specifically. You may use the same trick to draw everything else; another way is approximating your curve with subpixellic precision with splines, and draw the spline.